# Navigation problem with FutureBuilder and MaterialApp

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, future, flutter-navigation

My app has a state which is computed as a Future.
For example it includes a theme color, because I want to change the color when I navigate.
I try to display a progress indicator while waiting for the data.

But I can't make it work.
Either Navigator.push is not working and the app bar is missing, or I have no progress indicator and a route error...

Here is a code snippet.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Test());

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  Future<Color> color = Model.getColor();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Color>(
      future: color,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) throw snapshot.error;
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
          if (false) {
            // Navigation not working. App bar missing.
            return Material(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
          } else {
            // Progress not working. Screen flickering.
            return MaterialApp(home: _buildWait());
          }
        }
        var app = MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: snapshot.data),
          home: _buildPage(),
          // ERROR: The builder for route "/" returned null.
          // routes: {'/': (_) => _buildPage()},
        );
        return app;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPage() {
    return Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Push'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  color = Model.getColor();
                });
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar());
                }));
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildWait() {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Wait...')),
    body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
  );
}

class Model {
  static final _colors = [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.amber];
  static int _index = 0;
  static Future<Color> getColor() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => _colors[_index++ % _colors.length]);
  }
}
```

Expected result: when I push the button to navigate to the new route, it should display a progress indicator, and then the new screen with a different theme color.

Comment: You use a unnamed route. Actually every `named route` and `unnamed route` should be the descendant of `MaterialApp`, which means you can not change MaterialApp as you did because all routes are split from it. See the example of `named route` here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes

Comment: @yellowgray With named routes I have the error `The builder for route "/" returned null.`

Comment: hi @Patrick, what I have understand from your question is that, lets say you have 3 screens A,B, and C. All have AppBar, and you want different app bar color in every screen. right? lets say user navigate form A to B, B will have different NavBar color, loading widget and back button on AppBar. right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now try the following. Try to make a root widget separately, because root widget is always there. you don't want a complete UI route to persist in the memory. Also make next route as a separate widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  Future<Color> color = Model.getColor();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Color>(
      future: color,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Center(child: Text("An Error Occurred"));
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return _buildWait();
        }
        var app = Theme(
          data: ThemeData(primaryColor: snapshot.data),
          child: _buildPage(),
        );
        return app;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPage() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Push'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return NextRoute();
            }));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildWait() {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Wait...')),
    body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
  );
}

class Model {
  static final _colors = [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.amber];
  static int _index = 0;
  static Future<Color> getColor() {
    return Future.delayed(
        Duration(seconds: 2), () => _colors[_index++ % _colors.length]);
  }
}

class NextRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  NextRoute({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NextRouteState createState() => _NextRouteState();
}

class _NextRouteState extends State<NextRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Color>(
        future: Model.getColor(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("An Error Occurred"),
            );
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return _buildWait();
          }

          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData(primaryColor: snapshot.data),
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but 2 problems:
1) Failed assertion: 'data != null' in Theme().
2) There are 2 nested Scaffolds.

Comment: @Patrick I updated my code, try now. Remove the Theme widget you don't need that, also the top most scaffold.

Comment: It doesn't work, sorry. I edited the question to add the expected result.

Comment: Okay you want to change the color when you navigate. and use the color on same route? or in next route?

Comment: I want a different color for the next route.

Comment: Your NextRoute widget should probably be returned in the push() I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

so I think I have found the error, actually you must have an `MaterialApp` inside `runApp()` as root.

so you can't have `MaterialApp` inside `FutureBuilder`
what you can do is make `MaterialApp` the root widget and have a default Home Screen and inside its build method you can have your `FutureBuilder` but again don't include `materialApp` inside it just use Scaffold directly.

**EDIT :**
**To answer the question regarding app theme**

You can have switching themes by using
`theme` and `darkTheme` in materialApp And control `themeMode` from `Provider` or any other state management approach.

```
MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Tutorials',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
          darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
          themeMode: appState.isDarkModeOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
          home: ThemeDemo(),
        );
```

There are several ways to do it here is one more that I found [custom theme app](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/flutter-custom-dynamic-theme-b3e9b70fcd71)

Try this out it will work, if doesn't let me know

Comment: let me know if this solved the problem or not @patrick

Comment: I need to change the theme color of the app, so I can't have MaterialApp as root, I must have a parent widget to hold the theme state.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do as follow:

1. Move all Future data/FutureBuilder into different Stateless/Stateful Widget and override the theme color with `Theme` class

   ```
   class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       var color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

       return FutureBuilder(
         future: Model.getColor(),
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
           if (!snapshot.hasData) {
             return Theme(
               data: ThemeData(primaryColor: color), 
               child: _buildWait(),
             );
           } else {
             color = snapshot.data;
             return Theme(
               data: ThemeData(primaryColor: color),
               child: Scaffold(
                 appBar: AppBar(),
               ),
             );
           }
         },
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. The first page use the local variable to store color

   ```
   ...
   Color _primaryColor;

   @override
   void initState() {
     _primaryColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
     super.initState();
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
       theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: _primaryColor),
       home: _buildPage(),
     );
   }
   ...
   ```
3. If you want the first page update the theme on the same time, you should use some method to share data between widget (e.g. Provider). I use the simple method to catch the custom return value

   ```
   // First Page
   // use "then" can get the return value from the other route
   ...
   onPressed: () {
     Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
       return SecondPage();
     })).then((color) {
       setState(() {
         _primaryColor = color;
       });
     });
   },
   ...

   // Second Page
   // WillPopScope can catch navigator pop event
   ...
   return WillPopScope(
     onWillPop: () async {
       Navigator.of(context).pop(color);
       return Future.value(false);
     },
     child: FutureBuilder(
      ...
   ```

---

If it is not necessary for you to use `Routing` when you try to change Theme,
I can provide a simple solution that change the theme data by `Theme` class

```
ThemeData currentTheme;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  currentTheme = Theme.of(context);
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: FutureBuilder<Color>(
      future: color,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        Widget child;
        if (snapshot.hasError) throw snapshot.error;
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
          child =  Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        }else{
          currentTheme = currentTheme.copyWith(primaryColor: snapshot.data);
          child = _buildPage();
        }
        return Theme(
          data: currentTheme,
          child: child,
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Here is the document of [Themes for part of an application](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes#themes-for-part-of-an-application)

Comment: Yes I need to have different themes for different routes of the app, sorry.

Comment: Can you describe more detail `what happen/expected result` during route changing? Is future data ready before or after changing route?

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the `return Builder` section in the `_buildPage` widget and it seems to work. It also shows the `CircularProgressIndıcator` and `Wait...` text in `AppBar`.

Here is the edited code:

```
Widget _buildPage() {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Push'),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              color = Model.getColor();
            });
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar());
            }));
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the navigation does not work: there is no back button.

Comment: That's OK. I will try an another solution and when I found it, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Are you trying to change just the appBar color, or the whole theme color?

Comment: The whole theme.

Comment: I think we don't need to delay color. Why don't we delay the circular indicator instead? For example, show the indicator for two seconds, then show the color.